# Object initialization error SimpleDriverDataSource object with MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, jdbc

I need to set SimpleDriverDataSource object in order to create datasource with MongoDB, however I am not able to figure out what I should pass as "Driver".

I searched and found out that this is the JDBC driver for MongoDB "mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver", but how do I set it up while initializing SimpleDriverDataSource object?

I have tried doing the below, but it shows error mentioned below

```
@Bean
protected DataSource dataSource() {
    SimpleDriverDataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource(); 
    Driver driver = new Driver("mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver");         
    
    ds.setDriverClass(driver);
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017:spring-security-sampledb");
    ds.setUsername("root");
    ds.setPassword("secret");
    return ds;
}
```

error

> Cannot instantiate the type Driver

I am new to Spring Boot. Can you please help me in implementing this?

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

`java.sql.Driver` is **an interface**, which means you cannot instantiate it like that. You may want to review the basics of Java before starting with Spring Boot.

In any case, you need to use `new mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver()` instead of `new Driver()`, or use `setDriverClass` and pass it the class reference (`mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver.class`) instead of a `Driver` instance.

Also, please be aware that `SimpleDriverDataSource` is probably the wrong choice, as - for example - it doesn't provide connection pooling.

Comment: Which maven dependency do i need to have in order to be able to use "mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver()" or "mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver.class".
As of now i have these two for mongo= <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
   <version>3.12.11</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: @HimanshuChugh That is an entirely different question. I'd start with [Connect from JDBC Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/data-federation/query/sql/drivers/jdbc/connect/), which conveniently contains a link to Maven Central Search...